# Python partially outputs some values and fully outputs the last ones

Tags: python, sqlite, command-line-interface

Hello so I'm trying to get some data from different tables in SQLite3 using python
But it only gives the data from all tables on the last entry, If you don't understand what i mean here are some code snippets and the output

Here's the code

```
import sqlite3

def getBookingFromUsername(name):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE username = "{}"'.format(name))
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print("----------------Sessions------------------")
            print("ID: "+str(row[0]))
            print("Session ID: "+str(row[1]))
        sessionID=row[1]
        getSessionFromID(sessionID)
        return sessionID
    except:
        print("Oops something went wrong ")

def getSessionFromID(sessionID):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE id = "{}"'.format(sessionID))
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print("Session Date: "+str(row[1]))
            print("Session Time: "+str(row[2]))
            print("Vehicle Regsitration Number: "+str(row[4]))
        regNo=row[4]
        getPackageFromRegNo(regNo)
        return regNo
    except:
        print("Oops something went wrong ")

def getPackageFromRegNo(regNo):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM packages WHERE registrationNumber = "{}"'.format(regNo))
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print("Vehicle Type: "+str(row[1]))
            print("Tutor Name: "+str(row[3]))
            print("Session Duration: "+str(row[4])+"Hours")
            print("Price: RM"+str(row[6]))
            print("------------------------------------------")
    except:
        print("Oops something went wrong ")
```

Here's the output

```
----------------Sessions------------------
ID: 1
Session ID: 1
----------------Sessions------------------
ID: 2
Session ID: 6
Session Date: 16/03/2022
Session Time: 5:30 PM
Vehicle Regsitration Number: HGT5768
Vehicle Type: Motorbike
Tutor Name: Omar Solieman
Session Duration: 1.0Hours
Price: RM36.78
------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------
```

As you can see it only outputs the full data of the last entry

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Both of your calls to `getSessionFromID` and `getPackageFromRegNo` occur outside of their for loop, so they will only ever be called once.  Indent them one level, and they'll be called for each row.

Comment: Thank You so much!!! spent way too many hours trying to figure it out, THANK YOU!